# How do I loop through a directory path stored in a variable

Tags: bash

I'm teaching my self bash and trying to create a script that will loop through the directories contained within a given directory (or the current directory, if none is supplied).

This is the script I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
start_dir=${1:-`pwd`}       # set to current directory or user supplied directory
echo start_dir=$start_dir

for d in $start_dir ; do
    echo dir=$d
done
```

First, all this script currently does is sets `d` to  `start_dir` abd echos the value in `start_dir`.  I guess this makes sense, but I was hoping it would actually loop through the directory.  How do I get this to actually loop through the directory set in the `start_dir` variable?

Also, I'm wanting to only loop through the directories.  [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86724/90462), shows that putting a `/` after the path will ensure only directories are returned to the for loop.  Is there a way to incorporate this to ensure looping over `start_dir` will only return directories, given that there is a possibility that the user will not provide a directory path to the script?

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The example uses a glob, and so can you:

```
#!/bin/bash
start_dir=${1:-`pwd`}       # set to current directory or user supplied directory
echo "start_dir=$start_dir"

for d in "$start_dir"/*/ ; do
    echo "dir=$d"
done
```

`*` is not a directory name, it just means "any string". Bash expands it to find all paths matching the pattern.

Comment: Thanks.  Worked perfectly.  Also gave me a new term to investigate `glob`